# Is it permissible to use fractional aspect ratio W/L for MOSFETs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, design, ota

I am designing a 2-stage op-amp (Miller compensated). For compensation, I am using a nulling resistance **R** in series with the compensation capacitance **C**, *with the resistance implemented using a transistor biased in the triode region*.

The circuit is shown below:

[image]

Now, I noticed that I can play around with the Gain-bandwidth product and the phase-margin by just varying the aspect ratio of the triode transistor. I noticed that lowering the aspect ratio (hence increasing the resistance) increases the GBW. So I decided to lower it.

Is it justified to use a fractional aspect ratio **W/L**? Say, **W/L=0.5**. It is practical? Common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, it is done all the time in practice, especially when you want a device in triode.  I use it regularly in bias circuits or comparator preamps with triode loads.  From a practical standpoint, if you want to use a really long device, you shouldn't have the width at minimum but it is usually better to have it closer to 2x or 3x minimum.